# Get username from tty2 login at startup

Tags: 20.04

After installing some Nvidia drivers on my HP, running Ubuntu 20, the computer dosen't start anymore.

[startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K2bz.jpg)

I wanted to remove the drivers by opening the tty2 console.
My new problem is the login screen. I can't remember my username, but I know the password of my account.

Is there a way to get the username?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to recover my username by starting in command line/grub and then using `ls /home/`.
Starting from this point, I just needed to purge all new installed drivers from TTY2